# IntelliJ shows shorthand package names. How to see the actual package names?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5 and working on a Maven project, the package names in the project tab are showing up as `a.b.g.d` for a package named `alpha.beta.gamma.delta`. How can I see the actual package names? I tried using the filters and preferences but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on the cog icon at the top-right of the project view, uncheck the option "Abbreviate Qualified package names" (that's on v15, but I assume it's the same in v14).

Comment: Thats's what exactly I want.

Comment: This option is only available when you have enabled the "Flatten packages" option. It took me some time to figure out.

Comment: @TinusTate, yes and it also only work in the Project view... I was also looking that option while using "Project Files" / "Production" views but that option seems not available there.

Comment: @TinusTate  in the meantime (2021.3.1) this works in conjunction with "Flatten Packages" but the visibility of this option is flaky still. 
I had also switched to the projects files tab but that was not the only thing i had todo, but then it was suddenly there. Not sure what really caused it now to appear.